# J invariant as a solution to a cubic

Tags: modular-forms

In Starks proof of the class number 1 problem, on page 18 he mentions an equation derived by Weber that says: $\exists a,b,c\in Q(j(\frac{-3+\sqrt{d}}{2}))$ s.t. $j(\frac{-3+\sqrt{d}}{2})^3+aj(\frac{-3+\sqrt{d}}{2})^2+bj(\frac{-3+\sqrt{d}}{2})+c=0$. I cant find a free version of the paper, so I was wondering if anyone knows another source that derives this or if anyone can explain how to derive this. Thank you for any help!